# npm audit force increases vulnerabilities

Tags: npm, npm-audit, npm-vulnerabilities

it initially says 23 issues but after using audit fix --force, it tries to install some depricated files? i think and the vulnerabilities increase to 56. but after using audit fix force again, it goes back to 23...

```
PS C:\WORKSPACE\REACT\training\new\hey> npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 4.0.3,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.